# Google Play Services Achievements help (unity3d)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am using the script below for achievements in my android game using google play services, however the achievements seem to only pop up on the next game session, not during play can anyone help me please?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class main_achievements : MonoBehaviour {

    //public AudioClip achievement_sound;
    public int score;
    public int redcoin;
    public int lightningcollected;
    public int purple;
    public int blue;
    public int loop;
    public int submit;
    public int prize;
    public int coinscollected;
    public int jackpot;

void Start () {

        //initializing the social platform stuff
        //PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        //PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("currentscore",0);
        redcoin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("redcoin");
        lightningcollected = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lightningcollected");
        blue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("blue");
        purple = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("purple");
        loop = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("loop");
        submit = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("submit");
        prize = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("prize");
        coinscollected = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("currentcoins");
        jackpot = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("jackpot", jackpot);
    }

void Update() {

    //score for the first time achievement
    if (score > 1){
        Social.ReportProgress(
            "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQAg", 100.0f,
            (bool success) =>{
            });

            }

        //score 500 achievement
        if (score > 500){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQCQ", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //score 1000 coin hoarder achievement
        if (score > 1000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQCg", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //score 5000 coin treasurer achievement
        if (score > 5000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQCw", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //score 10000 stormer achievement
        if (score > 10000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQDA", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //score 15000 coin addict achievement
        if (score > 15000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQDQ", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //score 30000 coin dependent achievement
        if (score > 30000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQEg", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //score 100,000 coin god achievement
        if (score > 100000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQEw", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

            //activate bonus ring achievement
            if (redcoin == 1){
                Social.ReportProgress(
                    "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQAw", 100.0f,
                    (bool success) =>{
                });

                }

                //activate lightning achievement
                if (lightningcollected == 1){
                    Social.ReportProgress(
                        "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQBA", 100.0f,
                        (bool success) =>{
                    });

                    }
                    //collect 5 purple coins achievement
                    if (purple == 5){
                        Social.ReportProgress(
                        "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQCA", 100.0f,
                            (bool success) =>{
                        });

                        }
        //blue in the dropzone achievement
        if (blue == 1){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQBQ", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }


        //shoot the loop achievement
        if (loop == 1){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQBg", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //climb the ladder
        if (submit == 1){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQBw", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //first prize
        if (prize == 1){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQDg", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //pocket some coins achievement
        if (coinscollected > 100){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQDw", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //pockets full achievement
        if (coinscollected > 500){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQEA", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //pockets bursting achievement
        if (coinscollected > 1000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQEQ", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //coin Mountain achievement
        if (coinscollected > 2000){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQFA", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }

        //jackpot achievement
        if (jackpot == 3){
            Social.ReportProgress(
                "CgkI7_rqgYIcEAIQFQ", 100.0f,
                (bool success) =>{
            });

        }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you create Global achivement scripts (initilizations and functions unlock achievement etc.). Then you should, call appropriorate function you want to use during gameplay.

For example, an achievement like "Reach 1000 points". You should call related unlock achievement function in like UpdateScore.cs.

You use a flag to control any achievement do not always call unlock achievements.

Remember all Global scripts references keeps while running gameplay, all playerprefs keeps while game is uninstalled.